# Complex custom VF page that could query and perform calculations from up to 1.5kk Cases

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, governorlimits, limits

I was given a task: create a complex report based on VF page that queries up to **1.5kk cases** and represents it as a table with several variables in it. Let's say I need to get something like this:
[image]
The question is - how to do it in the best way(so the page not gonna hung for minutes or exceed CPU time limits and so on), keeping in mind that that page must be able to show the table as above from 1.5kk case records.
I see two possible approaches to solve the problem:

***First approach*** is bully - just SOQL all 1.5kk cases, calculate the needed fields(Status, Priority and so on) and print calculated items on the page.

***Second approach*** is to create a custom object, something like *DataForVFPage*, create a Schduled Batch to create a record per day with populated needed fields(number of new cases with priority "high" and more than 30 days from escalations...etc.), and then on my VF page just query those items(which will be only ~3700 records after 10 years), summarize them and show on VF page.

Right now **I'm thinking more to second approach**, since it'll allow to proceed any amount of records pretty fast, and seems the only way to do it properly.
**Is there any other approach? Maybe the above table could be done via reports?(not really familiar with their potential)**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with "kk". Do you mean to say "millions" of cases?

Comment: @sfdcfox, yes, 1.5 million of cases.

Comment: This looks like something you could build with a pretty basic report. Have you tried that?

Comment: @sfdcfox, no, I'm not that experienced with reports, so not sure what the could and couldn't do.

Comment: You can use a Summary report with some Summed fields, and perhaps a formula. Reports can show a lot of data without too much effort, and you don't need to build anything.

Comment: gonna try to do so with summary reports, thank you.